# How do I change a variable from a different class?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm trying to change the variable GameWeek from a method in a different class, but I can't get it to work.

In my Game1 constructor I create the class

```
public GameData currentGameData = new GameData();
```

The class I'm trying to change the GameWeek variable is created in the Game1 Load method:

```
startScreen = new StartScreen(this, globalVariables, currentGameData);
```

In the StartScreen class I have the following (constructor + next one or two lines):

```
GameData thisGameData

public StartScreen(Game1 game, GlobalVariables globalVariables, GameData gameData)
      : base(game)
{
  this.thisGameData = gameData;
```

I then modify thisGameData in a method in the startScreen class:

```
thisGameData.GameWeek = 1;  //this doesn't work
```

However, currentGameData in the Game1 class hasn't changed. This hardly seems surprising, my question is how to I go about actually doing this? As I understand it, when you pass a class in a constructor only the reference is passed, so even though the reference name is difference shouldn't it point to the same place (as they were set to be the same).

I feel like I've completely lost the plot / got something a bit backward here, but I can't figure this one out.

Any help much appreciated!

GameData class for reference:

```
public int gameWeek;
public int GameWeek
{
  get { return gameWeek; }
  set
  {
    if (gameWeek > 52)
    {
      gameWeek = 0;
      gameYear += 1;
    }
    else
    {
      gameWeek = value;
    }
  }
}

public int gameYear;
```

EDIT

To reclarify the question as I don't feel like I've phrased it very well.

If in my Game1 class I write:

```
currentGameData.gameWeek = 1;
```

Then it works.

What I want to achieve is exactly the same as that, but do it from the within the StartScreen class.

If I just write the above in my StartScreen class then it obviously doesn't work because currentGameData doesn't exist.

Comment: Is GameData a struct? Those are passed by value instead of by reference

Comment: Bingo!! Didn't know that, and changing it from struct to class fixes the problem. However, I would like to keep it as a struct if possible, do you know how I can do this by keeping it as a struct?

Comment: use the `ref` keyword to pass by reference. It's a bit nasty though. You're better off looking at why you need to do that & change your code so you don't need to.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, by the sounds of it I'm better off avoiding it than working out why it didn't work. What I am trying to achieve is to change the value of gameWeek within the startScreen class. I feel like this is definitely something that should be doable and think I'm probably missing something obvious

Comment: You could use properties in your Game1 class to modify the values directly. Then you could do game.GameWeek=1 without having to pass anything around.

Comment: Sorry stupid question time, what do you actually mean when you say "use properties.."?

Comment: yes, that edited response was a bit different.  You are looking for a global variable, which in this case should mean that you could reorganize the code a bit better than it is.  Also, does StartScreen inherit from another class that takes a Game1 object?

Comment: I added a bit of info to my answer using a ref parameter.  but the overall structure could be made better, like @AndrewSun mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, prior post was entered too quickly.

```
public int GameWeek
{
  get { return gameWeek; }
  set
  {
    if (value > 52) // value here was gameWeek.
    {
      gameWeek = 0;
      gameYear += 1;
    }
    else
    {
      gameWeek = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Do you also need to do something in your calling code to determine if the week is greater than 52?  E.g., your code will work in the GameWeek property if value is 53, but if it hits 54, the week would still be 0 and the year would increase by one, again.

EDIT: responding to poster's intended issue of not being able to set a value and have it reflect

I haven't worked a whole lot with C#, but it seems like you need a reference parameter to do what you are asking for, though it seems like a bad idea to do it that way.

```
startScreen = new StartScreen(this, globalVariables, ref currentGameData);


public StartScreen(Game1 game, GlobalVariables globalVariables, ref GameData gameData)
      : base(game)
{
  this.thisGameData = gameData;
  this.thisGameData.GameWeek = 1;
  // ...
}
```

BTW, you should put better snippets of code in for us, such as giving us the entire wrapper, like so:

```
// GameData class for reference:
class GameData {
  public int gameWeek;
  public int GameWeek
  {
    get { return gameWeek; }
    set
    {
      if (gameWeek > 52)
      {
        gameWeek = 0;
        gameYear += 1;
      }
      else
      {
        gameWeek = value;
      }
    }
  }

  public int gameYear;
} // end class GameData
```

That takes a lot less explaining =)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I see what you mean, but the problem I'm having is the value I want to change is currentGameData.gameWeek in the Game1 class, I just can't seem to access it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

declare it as
public static int gameweek;